# Spring support for Apache Geode (spring-data-geode)

Tags: spring-data-gemfire, geode

Could you please tell where to find out spring-data packages for [Apache Geode](http://geode.apache.org/)? There is a [spring-data-gemfire](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) project that produces regular releases for Pivotal Gemfire. spring-data-geode is supposed to be a part of this project but I am not able to find out any information about. There is just one artifact with version 1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE in Maven Central.

Thanks in advance,
Vadim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question!

There is a ***Spring Data Geode*** project, and you are correct, the latest version of *Spring Data Geode* is `1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE` (as seen in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-data-geode)).  That particular version of SD Geode is based on **Apache Geode** `1.0.0-incubating`, matching on version so users are clear which version of Apache Geode they get when declaring a dependency on SD Geode.

Being the *Spring Data Geode* project lead, I am acutely aware that *Apache Geode* released a 1.1.0 version at the end of February with a follow up 1.1.1 patch release in March (see [Releases on the Apache Geode page](http://geode.apache.org/releases/)).

Additionally, it has been sometime since I have cut a **new** release of *Spring Data Geode* to match the current version of *Apache Geode* (i.e. 1.1.1).  There are several reasons for this...

1. First, I am in the process of enhancing *Spring Data Geode's* new Annotation-based configuration model (*Spring Boot* style) to allow for dynamic configuration of key Annotation attributes (think port numbers used between clients and servers for instance) when using the Annotations while still preserving the strongly-typed nature of the attributes (i.e. not all `Strings`).  In a nutshell, I am accomplishing this with a standard convention often used in *Spring*, "*Configurers*", as well as "well-known and documented" properties rather than my previous intention (Property Placeholders and SpEL Expressions in Annotation attributes, which then would require them to be `Strings`, yuck).

> NOTE: The beginnings of this **new** Annotation model in SD Geode and GemFire was described in 1 of my [blogs](https://spring.io/blog/2016/10/11/spring-data-geode-1-0-0-apache-geode-incubating-m3-released#setting-the-stage). A subsequent follow-up [blog entry](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/10/spring-data-geode-1-0-0-incubating-release-released) specifically covered Annotation support for Geode's new Integrated Security Framework.

2. Second, I added [support in SD Geode](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/#bootstrap:lucene) for *Apache Geode's* **Lucene Integration**.
3. Lastly, *Spring Data Geode* used to exist in the [`apache-geode`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/tree/apache-geode) branch in the *Spring Data GemFire's* [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire).  However, since the last SD Geode release (i.e. `1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE`), **@Oliver Gierke** (*Spring Data Team Lead*) has agreed to make *Spring Data Geode* a **top-level** *Spring Data* project, like *Spring Data GemFire*, and so, *Spring Data Geode* will join the [*Spring Data Release Train*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay#core-themes), hopefully in the next *Spring Data* **Kay Milestone 4 (M4)** release.  However, this [depends entirely on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/pom.xml#L25) the upcoming *Apache Geode* **1.2.0 release** being released, first.  As you can see, there is already a [dedicated GitHub Repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode) specifically for the *Spring Data Geode* project now.

> NOTE: While all my doc references here have been to *Spring Data GemFire*, they equally apply to *Spring Data Geode*, especially as of the *Spring Data GemFire* **2.0.0 Milestone** releases (SD **Kay**) since SD *GemFire* is based on *Pivotal GemFire* **9.x**, which is based on *Apache Geode* **1.0.0-incubating**.

This means several things...

First, and most importantly, *Spring Data Geode* will have its own [spring.io project page](http://projects.spring.io) (under [*Spring Data*](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/)) and its own documentation, separate from *Spring Data GemFire*, identifying it as separate/individual and proper *Spring Data* project.

Second, there are many things changing in *Spring Data*... alignment with **Java 8**, core ***Spring Framework 5*** for Reactive/Functional architectures and significant changes in *Spring Data* itself.  See the ["core themes" in SD Kay](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay#core-themes) for more details. As such, *Spring Data Geode* based on Apache Geode 1.2.0 will be at version 2.0.0 (unlike *Apache Geode*), therefore, the version numbers between *Spring Data Geode* and *Apache Geode* going forward will no longer align.

However, on positive note, once in place, *Spring Data Geode* will move at a predictable release cadence along with the rest of the *Spring Data* modules, including *Spring Data GemFire*.  This means there will be a transition period to get all the bits in order though, and hence this seemingly gap in *Spring* support for the latest version of *Apache Geode* (i.e. **1.1.1**).

Having said that, I am still planning to release 1 more individual *Spring Data Geode* release (i.e. `1.1.1.RELEASE`) based *Apache Geode* **1.1.1**, hopefully soon.

In the interim, you can use the *Spring Data Geode* `1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE` with the latest version of *Apache Geode* (i.e. `1.1.1`) without incident by simply including the SD Geode `1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE` dependency and declaring a direct dependency on *Apache Geode* `1.1.1`, which will override the version of *Apache Geode* pulled in by SD Geode, in your application POM file like so...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-geode</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geode</groupId>
  <artifactId>geode-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- along with any other geode dependencies you need -->
```

Anyway, hope this helps and I am sorry about the delay; juggling many priorities at the moment.

Cheers,
John

Comment: You are welcome.  If you have any other questions, let me know.  Thanks.